# How do I determine the TTL of the Vault token the VaultClient acquires

Tags: ttl, vaultsharp

I'm currently handling the TTL expiring like this:

`Secret v2Secret;
try
{
    v2Secret = await this.vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(vaultPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (VaultApiException e)
{
    this.vaultClient.V1.Auth.ResetVaultToken();
    v2Secret = await this.vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(vaultPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
}`

Is there a way for me to check the TTL the vaultClient has *before* I make the first ReadSecretAsync call?

Answer (score 0):

The docs were missing on the VaultSharp methods that allow this. VaultSharp supports 2 ways to find TTL of a token.

1. A LookupToken api where you can explicitly pass in any Vault-Token.
2. Or a LookupSelf API, where the implicit current vault token info will be returned.

I have added the docs for it. Please refer to

https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/README.md#token-lookup-any-token

and

https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/README.md#token-lookup-calling-token